# How can I remove all special characters from the start and end of a string, expect # and ,?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have to remove all special characters except `#` and `,` from the start and the end of a string.

I tried something like this:

```
$q = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\(\) ]/', '', $q);
```

Comment: 1) Have you tried something ? 2) What are *special* characters for you?

Comment: all characters are special ;-)

Comment: @Dagon You mean all uppercase letters, which say to their little lowercase child letters, that they are something special and unique :]

Comment: @Rizier123 and give them awards for just showing up

Comment: Anju, [what about this](https://regex101.com/r/gP4hA3/1): `/^([^\da-z#,]+)|(?1)$/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

As you already used, I use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) here to replace every character at the start or at the end of a string which isn't `#` or `,`.

```
$q = preg_replace('/^[^#,]|[^#,]$/', '', $q);
```

regex explanation:

```
^[^#,]|[^#,]$
```

- 1st Alternative: **^[^#,]**

  - **^** [assert position at start](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) of the string
  - **[^#,]** match a single character not present in the [list](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) below

    - **#,** a single character in the list #, literally
- 2nd Alternative: **[^#,]$**

  - **[^#,]** match a single character not present in the [list](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) below

    - **#,** a single character in the list #, literally
  - **$** [assert position at end](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) of the string

Answer (score 0):

Put all the special characters in the array you want to remove & use it like this

```
str_replace(array(':', '\\', '/', '*','$','%'), ' ', $string);
```